# Convert QueryExpression to SQL string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

Is there some way how to convert QueryExpression to SQL statement?
eg this:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("entity");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("col1");
query.Criteria.AddCondition("col2", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1);
```

to

```
SELECT col1 FROM entity WHERE col2 = 1
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this anyway? Doesn't seem very practical.

Comment: It would help to mention what technology you're using. It looks like you're talking about the `QueryExpression` that lives in `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query` (that is, Microsoft Dynamics), but there are lots of providers that use this kind of approach to queries.

Comment: I would suggest you consider converting to FetchXML (conversion built-in to XRM) and write a converter from FetchXML to SQL.

Comment: @haag1 for testing and debugging

Comment: @NetMage Thank you, it helped.

Comment: @BananaCake of course.. duh, my apologies lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the query to FetchXML (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/sample-convert-queries-fetch-queryexpression) and then find some tools or libraries to convert the FetchXML to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking if there is an automated way to do this, and the short answer is **No**. Unless there is someone who took it upon themselves to write a library for this (which I haven't seen) it isn't something supported in .NET out of the box.

There are a few reasons for this but the most obvious is because QueryExpression implements features that are not natively supported in SQL. They are operations that can be performed by the Entity Framework because it can simply read all of the objects into memory and do whatever the heck it wants after that. With SQL, you have to send these instructions to the database server, and it needs to understand what you are telling it to do.

Again, I am not saying it is impossible. If you really wanted to, you could probably come up with some very creative ways to mimic what Entity Framework is doing, but it would be an uphill battle.

Comment: Yes, I tried to write something fast, but then I found the exact things you are writing. It is possible to write some library to do it, but it would be very annoying and long.